# How insert multiple value in Intermediate table through API

Tags: linq, vue.js, .net-core

I use to add value from the VUEJS where write code like this.

```
<multiselect v-model="schoolTypeform.schoolTypeId" :options="SchoolTypes" :multiple="true" :close-on-select="false" :clear-on-select="false" :preserve-search="true" placeholder="Pick School Type" label="name" track-by="name" :preselect-first="true">
```

and the JS code for this is written like this:

```
async addSchool() {
            this.isbtnLoading = true;
            this.isException = false;
            await this.axios.post(this.school, this.form).then(response => {
            this.addSchoolType(response.data);
            })
        },
        async addSchoolType(id) {
            this.isbtnLoading = true;
            this.isException = false;
            this.schoolTypeform.shoolId = id;
            await this.axios.post(this.apiBasedUrl + '/SchoolsSchoolType', this.schoolTypeform).then(response => {
             this.isbtnLoading = false; 
            });
```

Now my ER structure is given like this:

School:(Table1)

```
   public partial class Schools
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    // Navigation       
    public ICollection<SchoolsSchoolType> SchoolsSchoolTypes { get; set; }     
}
```

SchoolType:(Table2)

```
    public class SchoolType
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Navigation
    public ICollection<SchoolsSchoolType> SchoolsSchoolTypes { get; set; }
}
```

SchoolsSchoolType (It is Intermediate table): Here the relation between the above is many to many.

```
    public class SchoolsSchoolType
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid ShoolId { get; set; }
    public Schools Schools { get; set; }

    public Guid SchoolTypeId { get; set; }
    public SchoolType SchoolType { get; set; }
}
```

Here is repository method write for single value input, but I want to add here multiple value in the intermediates or junction table.

```
     public async Task<Guid> CreateSchoolsAsync(SchoolsCreateVm schoolsCreateVm)
        {
            if (_GpsContext != null)
             {
                 var schoolsEntity = new Schools()
             {
                 ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                 Name = schoolsCreateVm.Name, 
                 SchoolsSchoolTypes = new List<SchoolsSchoolType>()
             };

             var schoolType = new SchoolType();
             schoolsEntity.SchoolsSchoolTypes = new List<SchoolsSchoolType>
             {
                 new SchoolsSchoolType
                 {
                     ShoolId =schoolsEntity.ID,
                     SchoolTypeId =schoolType.Id
                 }
             };
             return schoolsEntity.ID;
         }
              return Guid.Empty
}
```

Controller code is written here:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostSchool([FromBody]SchoolsCreateVm schoolsCreateVm)
    {
        var result = await _schoolsRepository.CreateSchoolsAsync(schoolsCreateVm);
        if (result != null)
        {
            return Ok(result);
        }
        return NotFound();
    }
```

Here is viewmodel used by me:

```
 public class SchoolsCreateVm
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Guid> SchoolTypeId{ get; set; } // List type of for intermediate table
    public SchoolsCreateVm()
    {
        SchoolTypeId = new List<Guid>();
    }
```

How can insert many schooltype for a single school in the intermediates(many to many) relation table through the VUEJS multiple selects. [image: Here the image for multi selection value]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to find the solution...

```
 public async Task<Guid> CreateSchoolsAsync(SchoolsCreateVm schoolsCreateVm)
    {
        if (_GpsContext != null)
        {
          var schoolId = Guid.NewGuid();
          var schoolsEntity = new Schools()

            {
                ID = schoolId, //    1--[1,2,3]
                Name = schoolsCreateVm.Name,                     
            };
            // Here the code in which we can enter in the multiple table and Intermediate table
           var SchoolsSchoolTypeList = new List<SchoolsSchoolType>();

            foreach(var item in  schoolsCreateVm.SchoolTypeId)
            {
                SchoolsSchoolTypeList.Add(new SchoolsSchoolType
                {
                     Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                     ShoolId = schoolId,
                     SchoolTypeId = item,
                });
            }
            await _GpsContext.School.AddAsync(schoolsEntity);
            _GpsContext.SchoolsSchoolTypes.AddRange(SchoolsSchoolTypeList);//Enter here for intermediate table that is 'SchoolsSchoolTypes'
            await _GpsContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return schoolsEntity.ID;
        }
         return Guid.Empty;      
    }
```